# Время выполнения PHP-скрипта

Tags: php

Прошу помощи решить проблему...

У меня php скрипт выполняется ровно 150 секунд и обрывается, не выдавая никаких ошибок. По идее он должен выполнятся в два раза дольше. В .htaccess прописал ***php_value max_execution_time 0***, думал дело в этом, но не помогло.

Что еще может быть?

Comment: Приведите чуть больше информации. Как запускается скрипт? Что он  выполняет? Какая версия PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего в php.ini жестко ограничено время выполнения скриптов. Проверьте php.ini сервера. Посмотрите значения этих параметров:

```
max_execution_time
max_input_time
```

Answer (score 0):

Если не помогает

```
ini_set('max_execution_time',0);
```

то попробуйте

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Comment: ни то, ни то не помогает..

Answer (score 0):

включите отображение ошибок

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 display_errors(1);
```

и выставьте время лимита через php .htaccess не всегда работает.
[`set_time_limit()`](http://www.php.su/functions/?set_time_limit)

Comment: Вставил, но все равно не помогает. Php ошибок тоже не пишет..
Просто через 150 секунд пишет на странице "502 Bad Gateway
nginx/0.7.63" и обрывается скрипт..

Answer (score 0):

У вас nginx отваливается от апача, после чего обрубается скрипт.

1. Неправильное решение - править настройки нгинкса, чтобы он дожидался ответа апача. В случае виртуального хостинга вас саппорт пошлет в прекрасное далекое :)
2. Правильное решение - запускать скрипт через крон или ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Пропишите в настройках сайта по пути **etc/nginx/sites-available** в location / этот код и перезапустите nginx

```
fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;
fastcgi_connect_timeout 300s;
```